# Lightning Email Templates: Custom Merge Fields

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, email-template, merge-field

Is there anyway to reference a custom object field when creating a Lightning Email Template or are we limited to the options in merge field picker? I believe it is the latter, but want to verify.

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify as referring a custom object field in email template? You already have that available using merge fields on email template, and that merge fields are the only way you can access data in an email template.

Comment: Well using Lighting Email Templates there is option to choose the object as with Standard Templates.

Comment: I am not able to figure it out in my dev org, a screenshot here could be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean reference a custom object's lookup relationship fields?

You are definitely able to create Lightning Email Templates for a custom object, however you cannot get a hold of that object's lookup relationships fields. The only field you can reference is the name field `{{{CustomObject__c.LookupRelationship__c}}}` will give you the lookup's name field.

The workaround that has been suggested is to use formula fields on the custom object that reference any field you need from the lookup relationship and then use those in the template.

Here is an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Brk7AAC) to allow it.

The [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=handlebars_template_language.htm&type=5) for the HML merge language don't seem to mention that this is not possible, but I have tested it out and in HML it definitely can't be done.

I have not tested this out with the SML language; [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=email_template_convert_from_SML_to_HML.htm&type=5) are the docs on how to create a LEX email template with SML, but I don't think it'll be possible to pull in the relationship fields with SML either.

Comment: Glad to hear, which method did you use?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your custom object has a lookup field to the Contact object. otherwise I have found that it is not listed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/167562)